Characterize conditions in which Taylor moment approximation is good
I am working with the Projected Gaussian, or Angular Gaussian distribution, which is given by $z = \frac{x}{||x||}$, where $x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$. This is a distribution on the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
I have found Taylor approximations for both the first and the second moments of $z$, $\mathbb{E}(z)$ and $\mathbb{E}(zz^T)$ (this approximation is for the moments in the embedding space, not on the sphere itself). These approximations work very well for some values of the parameters $\mu$ and $\Sigma$, and less well for others. I am now trying to identify for what parameter values the approximation will be good or not.
I am thus wondering whether there is some principled way that I can think about this. I've seem related discussions on this site, such as this, but I'm not sure whether they are of help here. First, because these discussions tackle the broader discussion of what types of variables this approach works for. It mostly works for this variable here (which is bounded, and thus whose moments are under control), but for some parameters better than others. Second, because my Taylor approximations seem more complicated (e.g. the results below are the result of combining two Taylor approximations, one for each moment).
What I have done so far is some intuition-guided experimentation using the 2D case as an example. Because $z$ has varying degrees to which it deviates from a "simple" distribution (skweness, kurtosis, multimodality, etc) I am comparing the "nicer" versions of the distribution to the "uglier" versions (see below). My naive intuition says that the second-order Taylor approximation should be poorer for these uglier versions of the distribution, but I can't clearly see whether this is the case.
So, my question is, should I be content with analyzing some of these intuition-guided scenarios (and analyzing random samples of the parameters)? Or is there some more principled way to guide this exploration into when the approximations are best?
Examples of intuition-guided exploration:
As an example, below we set $\mu = \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right]$ (so it lays on the unit circle), and $\Sigma$ is such that one eigenvector is parallel and the other perpendicular to $\mu$. We change the eigenvalues so the distribution of $x$ gets progressively more 'stretched' along the axis perpendicular to $\mu$. We show the resulting empirical moments (red) and the taylor approximation (blue) and samples of $z$ in black:

We see that as the distribution gets more wrapped around the sphere, the approximation becomes worse, and at the end better again.
Below, a similar example but stretching the distribution of $x$ along the direction of $\mu$:

And below another example increasing the variance of $\Sigma$ in both directions:

